# Writing opencv mat to stdout

Tags: c++, opencv, stdout

I am trying to write a processed mat to STDOUT so that I can pipe it into ffmpeg, but I can't understand what the difference is exactly between

imencode and imread.

According to the opencv documentation

```
imencode : Encodes an image into a memory buffer.

imread : Loads an image from a file.
```

Isn't imread loading image data into a memory buffer as well? Can an opencv window be piped to another application?

Instead of using raspvid I would like to pipe ffmpeg my program's output, which would be the window that displays the processed window.

http://www.valmueller.net/stream-video-with-raspberry-pi-to-youtube/

Comment: Primary difference between `imread` and `imencode` is that the first is for input (encoded image, in this case in a file, read into a cv::Mat) and the second for output (cv::Mat written as an encoded image to a memory buffer). What exactly do you mean by "window be piped to another application"?

Comment: http://www.valmueller.net/stream-video-with-raspberry-pi-to-youtube/

I want to stream the opencv window that has the processed output into ffmpeg, then stream that to youtube.

Currently my opencv program shows the processed window using imshow("cctv", img); if I do ./main am I already piping to STDOUT?

Comment: @Zypps987, did you manage to pipe into ffmpeg? I want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`imread` is related to `imdecode`, while `imwrite` is related to `imencode`.

You can think of `imread` as:

1. read *as-is* the raw data buffer from an image file (jpg, png, etc...)
2. use `imdecode` to decode the raw data buffer to (usually, but depending on flags) a BGR image.

while `imwrite` is:

1. use `imencode` to decode into jpg, png, etc...  a (usually) BGR image to a raw data buffer.
2. write the raw data buffer *as-is* to disk.

The raw data buffer is a `vector<uchar>`.

Depending on your needs, you can put on `stdout`:

- the (usually) BGR buffer, which contains the a sequence of bytes BGRBGR...BGR. The byte array starts at `mat.data` and has length equals to: `mat.rows * mat.cols * mat.channels()`. This is valid for continuous matrices, but let's assume that this is the case for now.
- or the *decoded* jpg, png, etc... raw data buffer

Comment: Hmm... thanks for this explanation. I mention in a post above the details of what exactly I'm trying to do. I'm not sure of exactly what I need though :/

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV tutorial on *[Operations with Images](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d98/tutorial_mat_operations.html)* mentions that while `imread`/`imwrite` can be used for reading and writing to files, but to...

> Use `cv::imdecode` and `cv::imencode` to read and write an image from/to memory rather than a file.

So since we want to push the result to standard out, we need to use `imencode` to save the matrix data in a buffer (here assuming JPEG file format):

```cpp
cv::Mat fileToSend = # initialised somehow
std::vector<uchar> buffer;
cv::imencode(".jpg", fileToSend, buffer);
```

And then write the buffer data to standard out:

```cpp
std::fwrite(buffer.data(), 1, buffer.size(), stdout);
std::fflush(stdout);
return 0;
```